# Send page_size in http request (Django)

Tags: django, pagination, django-rest-framework

Is there any way to specify the page_size in the http request when using [Django Pagination](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#pagenumberpagination)? I want to use the default page_size when it's not sent in the request.

in my `settings.py`, I have:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_METADATA_CLASS': 'myApp.views.MyAppMetadata',
    'PAGINATE_BY': 20,
    'USE_ABSOLUTE_URLS': True,
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'rest_framework.filters.DjangoObjectPermissionsFilter',
        'rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend',
        'rest_framework.filters.OrderingFilter'
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'myApp.paginators.pagination.CustomPagination',
}
```

And this is my pagination class:

```
class CustomPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response(OrderedDict([
            ('count', self.page.paginator.count),
            ('next', self.get_next_link()),
            ('previous', self.get_previous_link()),
            ('current_page', self.page.number),
            ('total_pages', self.page.paginator.num_pages),
            ('results', data)
        ]))
```

How should the `page_size_query_param` parameter be set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The very same page that you link to says that you can define `page_size_query_param` to indicate the query parameter that determines the page size.

**Edit**

You can just set it on your pagination subclass.

```
class CustomPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using [Django Pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/pagination/)

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

objects = ['john', 'paul', 'george', 'ringo']
p = Paginator(objects, page_size)

page1_data = p.page(page_number)
```

You can now change the **page_size** by receiving it through params or by any other way you want to.

Note: The one you are using is the DRF Pagination.